# Selecting between rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am working with a rather noisy data set and I was wondering if there was a good way to selectively choose between two rows of data within a group or leave them alone. Logic-wise I want to filter by group and then build an if-else type control structure to compare rows based on the value of a second column.

Example:

```
Row ID  V1  V2  
1   1  blah 1.2 
2   1  blah NA 
3   2  foo  2.3 
4   3  bar  NA
5   3  bar  NA
```

I want to group by ID (1, 2, 3) then go to column V2 and choose for example,  row 1 over row 2 because row 2 has NA. But for rows 4 and 5, where both are 'NA' I want to just leave them alone.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

What you need might really depends on what you exactly have. In case of NAs, this might help:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Row = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  ID =  c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3),
  V1 = c("bla", "bla", "foo", "bla", "bla"),
  V2 = c(1.2, NA, 2.3, NA, NA), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

Comment: I don't think this works because it just deletes all rows that have any NAs in them. I don't want to do that, i want to choose a row that has non-NA result in V2 or keep them all if V2 only has NA results for that ID group.

Comment: Have a look at `is.na`. If you need further help provide an example with the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `purrr`. The idea is to `split` the data frame by `ID`. After that, apply a user-defineed function, which evaluates if all the elements in `V2` are `NA`. If `TRUE`, returns the original data frame, otherwise returns the subset of the data frame by filtering out rows with `NA` using `na.omit`. `map_dfr` is similar to `lapply`, but it can combine all the data frames in a list automatically. `dt2` is the final output.

```
library(purrr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  split(.$ID) %>%
  map_dfr(function(x){
    if(all(is.na(x$V2))){
      return(x)
    } else {
      return(na.omit(x))
    }
  })
dt2
#   Row ID   V1  V2
# 1   1  1 blah 1.2
# 2   3  2  foo 2.3
# 3   4  3  bar  NA
# 4   5  3  bar  NA
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Row ID  V1  V2  
1   1  blah 1.2 
2   1  blah NA 
3   2  foo  2.3 
4   3  bar  NA
5   3  bar  NA",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```